# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently I am working on a Search Component in ReactJS.
In this case I get  an "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')" - Error, while trying to display it on localhost:3000.

If I remove the [newItem], there would not be thrown an error.
It would be very cool, if someone could help.

Mainly the problem is the function search(items)..

```
function App() {
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [q, setQ] = useState("");
const [searchParam] = useState(["capital", "name"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setItems(result);

            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            }
        );
}, []);

function search(items) {
    return items.filter((item) => {
        return searchParam.some((newItem) => {
            return (
                item[newItem]
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
            );
        });
    });
}

if (error) {
    return <>{error.message}</>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <>loading...</>;
} else {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="search-wrapper">
                <label htmlFor="search-form">
                    <input
                        type="search"
                        name="search-form"
                        id="search-form"
                        className="search-input"
                        placeholder="Search for..."
                        value={q}
                        onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <span className="sr-only">Search countries here</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <ul className="card-grid">
                {search(items).map((item) => (
                    <li>
                        <article className="card" key={item.callingCodes}>
                            <div className="card-image">
                                <img src={item.flag} alt={item.name} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-content">
                                <h2 className="card-name">{item.name}</h2>
                                <ol className="card-list">
                                    <li>
                                        population:{" "}
                                        <span>{item.population}</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Region: <span>{item.region}</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Capital: <span>{item.capital}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Is newItem an object?

Comment: Can you share the items array?

Comment: Yeah that is most likely an Object. I get some results with index (0, 1, 2) with parameters like a: value, c: value and so on.. I am getting it from my database using the fetch method

Comment: you are trying to display an object in the UI as a string. 'toString' is expecting a string value. Instead, it got an object. so, it is throwing an error. You try like `item[newItem].city`

Comment: Oh fuck yes.. my fault.. Would it be possible to just take the values from the Object? I think then I could display it, right? 
I am not sure, would it go with Object.values()?

Comment: Yeah, If you want to iterate this object, then, you can use `Object.values()` or `Object. entries()` to convert the object to array and iterate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The big problem was this line:
item[newItem].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1

I just had to add ? .... so the corrected line would be:
item[newItem]?.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1

Answer (score 1):

The problem-line of my code was:

```
item[newItem].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

To "fix" I did this:

```
item[newItem]?.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).